# How to claim venue using Venues & Venues Platform

Tags: api, foursquare, claims

I am developing application which uses foursquare API.
The app uses private DB (app users & account) but will need to associate (& claim) foursqure venue.
For example, user A is owner of foursquare venue , how can i sync (link) the private user A (user in our app) with the specific venue in foursquare?

Another issue, Does the API support creating and claiming (verify) venues?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We don't publicly expose a way to claim venues via the API. However, if you allow your users to [connect](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) to your app and they happen to already have claimed their venue on Foursquare, you'll surely be able to [detect](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pages/managing) this and mark this user in your own private DB as managing a venue on Foursquare.